# Developer Options screen opens for a second, then closes

Tags: usb-debugging, developer-options

I'm using an LG4c Android v5.0.2.  I have enabled Developer Options - it is in the menu where I can tap it to open it.
When I tap it, it opens for a split second - long to enough to see that it is on (blue button is on) and but turns off almost instantly so that in effect I cannot access it.
How can I get it to stay on?  Why does it not stay on?

Answer (score 1):

try it by going on safe mode(hold the power off option and click ok), after that use the developer options and by the same procedure , reboot into normal mode.

Comment: Hi.Thanks. I tried it but it didn't work either.  Same behaviour.  Screen opens for a split second and disappears before I can do anything.